# Efficient implementation of 2-d circularly symmetric low-pass filter

Tags: image-processing, filters, filter-design, 2d

How can a two-dimensional [ideal circularly symmetric low-pass filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58301/2-d-circularly-symmetric-low-pass-filter) or its approximation be efficiently implemented on data sampled on a square grid? I'm referring to an ideal filter with a spatial frequency response that equals $1$ inside radius $\omega_c$ (the cutoff frequency) and zero outside it, and with ideal impulse response:

$$h[x,y] = \frac{\omega_c}{2\pi \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} } J_1 \big( \omega_c \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \big).$$

A "not efficient" approach is to convolve with a 2-d filter kernel that is the product of $h[x, y]$ and a circularly symmetric window function.

Comment: I guess you also expect a computational efficiency due to the circular symmetry. A good deal of patience and circular math should be spent on it to see...

Comment: @Fat32 Maybe it can be approximated with the real part of a weighted sum of 2-d Gaussian filters with complex variance, each filter separable to a cascade of a vertical and a horizontal 1-d filter.

Comment: It seems you want to try ;-) So you would benefit from separability...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Approximation by the real part of a weighted sum of separable complex Gaussian component kernels

[image]
*Figure 1. The proposed scheme illustrated as 1-d real convolutions ($*$) and additions ($+$), for cut-off frequency $\omega_c = \pi/4$ and kernel width $N=41$. Each the upper and the lower half of the diagram is equivalent to taking the real part of a 1-d horizontal and a 1-d vertical pass separable 2-d complex convolution. Except for truncation/cropping, the two final components summed and the resulting kernel are guaranteed circularly symmetrical due to use of complex-number-weighted complex-variance Gaussian 1-d kernels.*

[I have suggested](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=1495) this approach for this problem, but not tried it before. A discrete-space 2-d convolution kernel (impulse response) $h[x, y]$ that is circularly symmetric (see Eq. 4) about $[0, 0]$, can be approximated to arbitrary accuracy by the real part of a separable (see Eq. 3) complex number weighted sum of Gaussian functions of complex variance:

$$h[x, y] \approx \tilde h[x, y],\tag{1}$$

$$\begin{align}\tilde h[x, y] = &\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\operatorname{Re}\left(a_m^2e^{b_m(x^2+y^2)}\right)\tag{2}\\
= &\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\operatorname{Re}\left(a_m e^{b_m x^2}\times a_m e^{b_m y^2}\right)\tag{3}\\
= &\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}\operatorname{Re}\left(a_m^2 e^{b_m r^2}\right)\tag{4}\\
= &\sum_{m=0}^{M-1}e^{\operatorname{Re}(b_m)r^2}\Big({\big(\operatorname{Re}(a_m)^2 - \operatorname{Im}(a_m)^2\big)\cos\big(\operatorname{Im}(b_m)r^2\big)\\
- 2\operatorname{Re}(a_m)\operatorname{Im}(a_m)\sin\big(\operatorname{Im}(b_m)r^2\big)\Big),}\tag{5}\end{align}$$

where $x$ and $y$ are integer horizontal and vertical coordinates, $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the radius or distance between $[0, 0]$ and $[x, y]$, $M$ is the approximation order, and $a_m$ and $b_m$ are complex amplitude and variance related coefficients.

### Optimized approximation, $\omega_c = \pi$

Eq. 5 with $r^2 = x^2 + y^2$ can be numerically optimized by global optimization to approximate a given $h[x, y]$ in spatial domain within the square $-(N-1)/2 \le x \le (N-1)/2$, $-(N-1)/2 \le y \le (N-1)/2$ with odd width $N$ of the square kernel. It suffices to do the optimization over a triangle $0 \le y \le (N-1)/2$, $y \le x \le (N-1)/2$. If the cost function is a sum of squares of errors or another sum of errors at each $(x, y)$, then cumulative $2\times$ error multipliers should be applied for each satisfied condition $x > 0$, $y > 0$, $x > y$.

The following C++ program optimizes the approximate kernel $\tilde h$ in spatial domain least squares sense using Differential Evolution from an [optimization library](http://yehar.com/blog/?p=643). The target kernel $h$ is windowed using a 2-d rotated cosine window. The source code includes pre-optimized approximations for cut-off frequency $\omega_c = \pi$, kernel size $N=41$, and approximation orders $1 \le m \le 5$.

```
// -*- compile-command: "g++ -Wno-unused-result -march=native -O3 -ffast-math optitest.cpp opti.cpp" -*-
// This file is optitest.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include "opti.hpp"
#include "keyboard.h"

double optimal0[4] = { // Dummy starting point for optimization
  0,0,0,0
};

double optimal1[1*4] = {//bestcost=0.03593696209385285195 Least squares
  0.90954095944946312,0.21237789645057972,-0.72663606661376057,0.76147736559107793
};

double optimal2[2*4] = {//bestcost=0.01072419992771576382 Least squares
  -0.14935266179235707,0.28729650415029556,-0.08227954155725942,0.36475170816661134,1.03225137134955114,0.47158356759095016,-0.60039465413238513,0.47344404338750434
};

double optimal3[3*4] = {//bestcost=0.00322191268986909149 Least squares
  -0.00646998371362690,-0.15983965263134517,-0.02321635125852370,0.20289085505437962,-0.30298121364781033,0.34395623806288950,-0.10323939264492392,0.32564190139614663,1.13148495464950427,0.66639187966234981,-0.54567361845465989,0.37519342198291905
};

double optimal4[4*4] = {//bestcost=0.00089888657916611925 Least squares
  0.04481214216545543,0.08998210660870602,-0.01130470880820374,0.14003687599487286,0.02506113778123746,-0.24720956687380186,-0.03419309947921907,0.19643391040650712,1.27604032320787875,0.91159589755622883,-0.49585695598458995,0.29480666144138823,0.48259638667856242,-0.42280882153371496,-0.12730997070336811,0.29988730534029784
};

double optimal5[5*4] = {//bestcost=0.00017259634849055045 Least squares
  -0.06413980110992069,-0.03272558679644168,-0.00736621171073370,0.10943881870260203,0.08213936888117918,0.16226536153011967,-0.01975126456281387,0.13958603391531316,-0.07270617897425770,0.37473199916953354,-0.04702984945995840,0.18925309227383197,1.43523098843984531,1.17056740170289952,-0.45755771004055446,0.24332707322808175,0.69700596730108921,-0.48854609666142051,-0.14144974773647198,0.27672159791886242
};

const int numOptimalKernels = 5;
double *optimalKernels[numOptimalKernels + 1] = {optimal0, optimal1, optimal2, optimal3, optimal4, optimal5};

class CircularLPProblem : public Opti::Problem {
private:
  double *minimum;
  double *maximum;
  int numComponents;
  int numSamples;
  int *r2s;
  int *multipliers;
  double *target;
public:

  int getNumDimensions() {
    return numComponents*4;
  }

  double *getMin() {
    return minimum; 
  }

  double *getMax() {
    return maximum; 
  }

  double costFunction(double *params, double compare) {
    for (int m = 0; m < numComponents; m++) {
      params[4*m + 2] = -fabs(params[4*m + 2]);
      params[4*m + 3] = fmod(fabs(params[4*m + 3]), M_PI);
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < numComponents - 1; m++) {
      if (params[4*m + 3] > params[4*(m + 1) + 3]) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
          double temp = params[4*m + k];
          params[4*m + k] = params[4*(m + 1) + k];
          params[4*(m + 1) + k] = temp;
        }
      }
    }
    double cost = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < numSamples; k++) {
      double r2 = r2s[k];
      double trial = 0;
      for (int m = 0; m < numComponents; m++) {
        //  trial += exp(params[4*m + 2]*r2)*(params[4*m + 0]*cos(params[4*m + 3]*r2) + params[4*m + 1]*sin(params[4*m + 3]*r2)); // Max absolute error
        trial += exp(params[4*m + 2]*r2)*((params[4*m + 0]*params[4*m + 0] - params[4*m + 1]*params[4*m + 1])*cos(params[4*m + 3]*r2) - 2*params[4*m + 0]*params[4*m + 1]*sin(params[4*m + 3]*r2)); // Least squares
      }      
      /*      if (fabs(trial - target[k]) > cost) { // Max absolute error
              cost = fabs(trial - target[k]);
              }*/
      cost += (trial - target[k])*(trial - target[k])*multipliers[k]; // Least squares
      if (cost > compare) {
        return cost;
      }
    }
    return cost;
  }

  // numComponents = number of components
  // N = kernel width
  // omega_c = cutoff frequency (radians)
  // Parameter vector: Re(a_0), Im(a_0), Re(b_0), Im(b_0), Re(a_1), ...
  CircularLPProblem(int numComponents, int N, double omega_c = M_PI): numComponents(numComponents) {
    numSamples = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < (N-1)/2 + 1; y++) {
      numSamples += (N-1)/2 + 1 - y;
    }
    r2s = new int[numSamples];
    multipliers = new int[numSamples];
    target = new double[numSamples];
    int k = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < (N-1)/2 + 1; y++) {
      for (int x = y; x < (N-1)/2 + 1; x++) {    
        r2s[k] = x*x + y*y;
        target[k] = omega_c*j1(omega_c*sqrt(x*x + y*y))/(2*M_PI*sqrt(x*x + y*y));
        double window = cos(M_PI/2*sqrt(pow(x/((N - 1)/2 + 1.0), 2) + pow(y/((N - 1)/2 + 1.0), 2)));
        if (window < 0) {
          target[k] = 0;
        } else {
          target[k] *= window;
        }           
        multipliers[k] = ((x > 0) ? 2 : 1) * ((y > 0) ? 2 : 1) * ((x > y) ? 2 : 1);
        k++;    
      }
    }
    target[0] = omega_c*omega_c/(4*M_PI);
    minimum = new double[4*numComponents];
    maximum = new double[4*numComponents];
    k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4*numComponents; i++) {
      minimum[i] = optimalKernels[numComponents - 1][k]-pow(0.1, numComponents - 1);
      maximum[i] = optimalKernels[numComponents - 1][k]+pow(0.1, numComponents - 1);
      k++;
      if (k >= (numComponents-1)*4) {
        k -= 4;
        if (k < 0) {
          k = 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  ~CircularLPProblem() {
    delete[] minimum;
    delete[] maximum;
    delete[] r2s;
    delete[] multipliers;
    delete[] target;
  }
};

int main() 
{
  INITKEYBOARD;

  CircularLPProblem problem(1, 41, M_PI); // Parameterize this!

  Opti::Strategy *optimizer;

  //optimizer=new Opti::G3(&problem, 2000);
  optimizer=new Opti::DE(&problem, 2000);

  printf("\nOptimizing...\n\n");

  for(int t = 0;; t++) {
    double bestcost = optimizer->evolve();
    if (!(t % 1000)) {
      printf("gen=%d, bestcost=%.20f, average=%.20f\n", t, bestcost, optimizer->averageCost());
      if (kbhit()) {
        printf("Parameter vector printout:\n");
        problem.print(optimizer->best());
        if (getch() == 27) break;
        getch();
      }
    }
  }
  delete optimizer;

  DEINITKEYBOARD;
  return 0;
}
```

[image]
*Figure 2. Sum-of-squares cost of the best found approximate kernel $\tilde h$ as function of approximation order $M$, for $\omega_c = \pi$, $\omega_c = \pi/2$, and $\omega_c = \pi/4$, and $N=41$. A good indicator that these are the globally optimal parameterizations is the steady decrease of error as $M$ is incremented, except for $\omega_c = \pi/4$, $M=3$ for which we might (or not) have a sub-optimal solution.*

This Python script generates the "exact" (windowed) kernel for comparison and implements the approximations:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import special
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage
import skimage
import time

def circularLowpassKernel(omega_c, N):  # omega = cutoff frequency in radians (pi is max), N = horizontal size of the kernel, also its vertical size, must be odd.
  kernel = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: omega_c*special.j1(omega_c*np.sqrt((x - (N - 1)/2)**2 + (y - (N - 1)/2)**2))/(2*np.pi*np.sqrt((x - (N - 1)/2)**2 + (y - (N - 1)/2)**2)), [N, N])
  kernel[(N - 1)//2, (N - 1)//2] = omega_c**2/(4*np.pi)
  return kernel

def rotatedCosineWindow(N):  # N = horizontal size of the targeted kernel, also its vertical size, must be odd.
  return np.fromfunction(lambda y, x: np.maximum(np.cos(np.pi/2*np.sqrt(((x - (N - 1)/2)/((N - 1)/2 + 1))**2 + ((y - (N - 1)/2)/((N - 1)/2 + 1))**2)), 0), [N, N])

N = 41  # Kernel width
M = 1  # Number of components
omega_c = np.pi  # Cutoff frequency <= np.pi
kernel = circularLowpassKernel(omega_c, N)*rotatedCosineWindow(N)

def saveKernel(name, kernel):
  plt.imsave(name+'.png', plt.cm.bwr(plt.Normalize(vmin=-kernel.max(), vmax=kernel.max())(skimage.transform.rescale(kernel, 4, 0))))
  absF = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(kernel)))
  plt.imsave(name+'_dft.png', plt.cm.Greys(plt.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=absF.max())(skimage.transform.rescale(absF, 4, 0))))

saveKernel('exactpi', kernel)

plt.imsave('bwrkey.png', plt.cm.bwr(np.repeat([(np.arange(41*4)/(41*4-1))], 16, 0)))
plt.imsave('Greyskey.png', plt.cm.Greys(np.repeat([(np.arange(41*4)/(41*4-1))], 16, 0)))

def reComponentKernel(N, param):
  x = np.arange(N)-(N - 1)//2
  return np.exp(param[2]*x**2)*(param[0]*np.cos(param[3]*x**2) - param[1]*np.sin(param[3]*x**2))

def imComponentKernel(N, param):
  x = np.arange(N)-(N - 1)//2
  return np.exp(param[2]*x**2)*(param[1]*np.cos(param[3]*x**2) + param[0]*np.sin(param[3]*x**2))

optimal1pi = [0.90954095944946312,0.21237789645057972,-0.72663606661376057,0.76147736559107793]
optimal2pi = [-0.14935266179235707,0.28729650415029556,-0.08227954155725942,0.36475170816661134,1.03225137134955114,0.47158356759095016,-0.60039465413238513,0.47344404338750434]
optimal3pi = [-0.00646998371362690,-0.15983965263134517,-0.02321635125852370,0.20289085505437962,-0.30298121364781033,0.34395623806288950,-0.10323939264492392,0.32564190139614663,1.13148495464950427,0.66639187966234981,-0.54567361845465989,0.37519342198291905]
optimal4pi = [0.04481214216545543,0.08998210660870602,-0.01130470880820374,0.14003687599487286,0.02506113778123746,-0.24720956687380186,-0.03419309947921907,0.19643391040650712,1.27604032320787875,0.91159589755622883,-0.49585695598458995,0.29480666144138823,0.48259638667856242,-0.42280882153371496,-0.12730997070336811,0.29988730534029784]
optimal5pi = [-0.06413980110992069,-0.03272558679644168,-0.00736621171073370,0.10943881870260203,0.08213936888117918,0.16226536153011967,-0.01975126456281387,0.13958603391531316,-0.07270617897425770,0.37473199916953354,-0.04702984945995840,0.18925309227383197,1.43523098843984531,1.17056740170289952,-0.45755771004055446,0.24332707322808175,0.69700596730108921,-0.48854609666142051,-0.14144974773647198,0.27672159791886242]

class SeparableCircularLowpassFilter:
  def __init__(self, N, coefs):
    self.N = N
    self.reKernels = []
    self.imKernels = []
    for i in range(len(coefs)//4):
      self.reKernels.append(np.array([reComponentKernel(N, coefs[i*4:])]))
      self.imKernels.append(np.array([imComponentKernel(N, coefs[i*4:])]))
  def filter(self, x):    
    reZ = scipy.ndimage.convolve(scipy.ndimage.convolve(x, self.reKernels[0].transpose()), self.reKernels[0]) - scipy.ndimage.convolve(scipy.ndimage.convolve(x, self.imKernels[0].transpose()), self.imKernels[0])
    for i in range(1, len(self.reKernels)):
      reZ += scipy.ndimage.convolve(scipy.ndimage.convolve(x, self.reKernels[i].transpose()), self.reKernels[i]) - scipy.ndimage.convolve(scipy.ndimage.convolve(x, self.imKernels[i].transpose()), self.imKernels[i])
    return reZ

filter1pi = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal1pi) # 1 component kernel
filter2pi = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal2pi) # 2 component kernel
filter3pi = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal3pi) # 3 component kernel
filter4pi = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal4pi) # 4 component kernel
filter5pi = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal5pi) # 5 component kernel

x = np.zeros([N, N])  # Input image 
x[N//2, N//2] = 1     # (unit impulse)
# x = plt.imread('sample.tif').astype(float)[:,:,1]  # (green channel of some image from file)

t0 = time.time()
Z = scipy.ndimage.convolve(x, kernel)  # Exact
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)

t0 = time.time()
reZ1pi = filter1pi.filter(x)  # 1 component kernel
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
saveKernel('reZ1pi', reZ1pi)

t0 = time.time()
reZ2pi = filter2pi.filter(x)  # 2 component kernel
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
saveKernel('reZ2pi', reZ2pi)

t0 = time.time()
reZ3pi = filter3pi.filter(x)  # 3 component kernel
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
saveKernel('reZ3pi', reZ3pi)

t0 = time.time()
reZ4pi = filter4pi.filter(x)  # 4 component kernel
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
saveKernel('reZ4pi', reZ4pi)

t0 = time.time()
reZ5pi = filter5pi.filter(x)  # 5 component kernel
t1 = time.time()
print(t1-t0)
saveKernel('reZ5pi', reZ5pi)
```

[image][image]$M=1$
[image][image]$M=2$
[image][image]$M=3$
[image][image]$M=4$
[image][image]$M=5$
[image][image]
[image][image]**exact**
*Figure 3. Kernels and the absolute value of their discrete Fourier transform (DFT), enlarged by a factor of 4 to make individual pixels visible. Top to bottom: Optimal approximating kernels $\tilde h$ with $M = 1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$ complex separable components, ideal kernel $h$ for $\omega_c = \pi$ and $N = 41$. Color keys: kernel: blue negative, white zero, red positive (normalized); abs DFT: white zero, black maximum.*

### Optimized approximation, $\omega_c = \pi/2$

Approximation of lower-cutoff kernels works better with this approach. I think this is because the number of ripples that fit in the windowed target kernel are reduced. For a high-cutoff filter then perhaps the kernel width $N$ could be reduced, as this would give the same number of ripples and frequency-domain approximation accuracy. But that would then favor a direct 2-d implementation (see Fig. 6). The C++ source code in the above was modified (not shown) for $\omega_c = \pi/2$ (and later for $\omega_c = \pi/4$) and the obtained parameters were used in a Python implementations of the approximate isotropic low-pass filters: (continued from the previous script)

```
omega_c = np.pi/2
kernelpi2 = circularLowpassKernel(omega_c, N)*rotatedCosineWindow(N)
saveKernel('exactpi2', kernelpi2)

optimal1pi2 = [0.44103810622146067,0.08998875769710178,-0.17010258583392401,0.19960767673288432]
optimal2pi2 = [-0.07233719880423649,0.14289630144713414,-0.02205699413927855,0.09165233018125875,0.51013245392078410,0.22632987351129516,-0.15215724343836151,0.12131467270512424]
optimal3pi2 = [-0.03867959516035375,-0.07754823299868645,-0.00905504286350691,0.05573851697983074,0.60460672854618647,0.36747347219951876,-0.13550005930232881,0.08061493799161984,-0.15528642640407436,0.23307152837452039,-0.03561076440525033,0.08259420496099962]
optimal4pi2 = [0.06323093028956613,0.02993129946018375,-0.00937470404526276,0.03826932634049100,0.78321346985185014,0.58823521191007977,-0.11611698422922974,0.05181454568143690,-0.07541120991444331,-0.16653642294319324,-0.01587217217852400,0.05400812761661748,-0.30454011473801174,0.38069299325271988,-0.04600795167685135,0.07149320869042795]

filter1pi2 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal1pi2) # 1 component kernel
filter2pi2 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal2pi2) # 2 component kernel
filter3pi2 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal3pi2) # 3 component kernel
filter4pi2 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal4pi2) # 4 component kernel

reZ1pi2 = filter1pi2.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ1pi2', reZ1pi2)
reZ2pi2 = filter2pi2.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ2pi2', reZ2pi2)
reZ3pi2 = filter3pi2.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ3pi2', reZ3pi2)
reZ4pi2 = filter4pi2.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ4pi2', reZ4pi2)
```

[image][image]$M=1$
[image][image]$M=2$
[image][image]$M=3$
[image][image]$M=4$
[image][image]
[image][image]**exact**
*Figure 4. Kernels and the absolute value of their discrete Fourier transform (DFT), enlarged by a factor of 4 to make individual pixels visible. Top to bottom: Optimal approximating kernels $\tilde h$ with $M = 1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$ complex separable components, ideal kernel $h$ for $\omega_c = \pi/2$ and $N = 41$. Color keys: kernel: blue negative, white zero, red positive (normalized); abs DFT: white zero, black maximum.*

### Optimized approximation, $\omega_c = \pi/4$

In Python: (continued from the first Python script)

```
omega_c = np.pi/4
kernelpi4 = circularLowpassKernel(omega_c, N)*rotatedCosineWindow(N)
saveKernel('exactpi4', kernelpi4)

optimal1pi4 = [0.22210250507512549,0.04738076096442791,-0.04565916667208288,0.04924268271256500]
optimal2pi4 = [0.28445762468654334,0.14050386040493884,-0.03988634664177378,0.02123143861749057,-0.01717623293554685,0.11158938041615812,-0.01191733840600387,0.02614013272136841]
optimal3pi4 = [-0.00332428227606697,0.01722626235358831,-0.00516799783527921,0.00727825629264402,0.30296628929626013,0.16328004086794692,-0.03813290200362767,0.01805103148816284,-0.02296006483369628,0.12768470633404483,-0.01299438181561595,0.02558273151301529]

filter1pi4 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal1pi4) # 1 component kernel
filter2pi4 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal2pi4) # 2 component kernel
filter3pi4 = SeparableCircularLowpassFilter(N, optimal3pi4) # 3 component kernel

reZ1pi4 = filter1pi4.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ1pi4', reZ1pi4)
reZ2pi4 = filter2pi4.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ2pi4', reZ2pi4)
reZ3pi4 = filter3pi4.filter(x)
saveKernel('reZ3pi4', reZ3pi4)
```

[image][image]$M=1$
[image][image]$M=2$
[image][image]$M=3$
[image][image]
[image][image]**exact**
*Figure 5. Kernels and the absolute value of their discrete Fourier transform (DFT), enlarged by a factor of 4 to make individual pixels visible. Top to bottom: Optimal approximating kernels $\tilde h$ with $M = 1$, $2$ and $3$ complex separable components, ideal kernel $h$ for $\omega_c = \pi/4$ and $N = 41$. Color keys: kernel: blue negative, white zero, red positive (normalized); abs DFT: white zero, black maximum.*

### Computational complexity

Complexity as the number of 1-d dot products of length $N$ per pixel is $4M$ for the approximations and $N$ for the naive 2-d convolution implementation. The approximations suffer from an additional performance overhead due to the use of additional memory for storing intermediate results.

[image]
*Figure 6. Complexity as the number of real multiplications per pixel vs. kernel width $N$. In reality the approximations are not quite as efficient, see Fig. 7. Possible advantages from symmetry of the kernels has not been taken into account.*

[image]
*Figure 7. Actual measured run time in seconds for 2-d convolution of a 5424×3636-pixel single-channel image by the ideal kernel $h$ and by separable approximating kernels $\tilde h$ with $M = 1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and $5$ complex separable components, for $N = 41$, using Python's `scipy.ndimage.convolve`.*

### Further ideas

In order to adjust $\omega_c$ without kernel parameter re-optimization, a nearly continuous approximating kernel could be optimized by using a small $\omega_c$ and a large $N$. The result could then be sampled using interpolation.

It would be interesting to try direct optimization of the complex kernels without a parameterization that enforces circular symmetry. Perhaps the approximation could even be optimized as a sum of $M$ real separable kernels, similar to [this Mathematics Stack Exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210565/approximate-a-convolution-as-a-sum-of-separable-convolutions). Also minimization of (least squares) error in the frequency domain is something to try.

Comment: Ok. That's another great answer from Olli :-) !

Comment: Nevertheless, I must confess the disappointment I had when I saw the **numerical optimization** for the approximation of the circular impulse response by a sum of complex weighted complex variance Gaussian kernels. I was expecting some analytical expressions for computing those complex weights and complex variances ;-) apart from kidding, the effort went into the numerical method is also breathtaking !

Comment: The only objection I would have would be on the justification of using **complex weighted complex variance** Gaussian kernels: and then taking their real parts anyway? Why cannot you directly start with plain real weighted real Gaussians; may be with more real parameters though. Furthermore, in your justificaiton of the **circularity** of the approximation, i think it's only about the term **x^2+y^2** and not about the complexness of the approximating kernels? Am I right ? Would the approximation still be circularly symmetric for a complex-kernel of $b \cdot e^{a(x+y)}$, for complex $a,b$ ?

Comment: @Fat32 According to my tests, you would not get convergence of the approximation with real-weighted real Gaussians. They do give circular symmetry though. $b \cdot e^{a(x+y)}$ does not give circular symmetry.

Comment: Hmm, the following type of kernels $ a e^{b(x^2+y^2)} \cos(b(x^2+y^2)) $, $ a e^{b(x^2+y^2)} \sin(b(x^2+y^2)) $ or their linear combination with real $a,b$ could possibly be converging...

Comment: @Fat32 however, they are not separable. If a kernel is circularly symmetric, it is separable only if it is Gaussian. This is [well known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1306695/gaussian-is-the-only-radial-function-which-is-separable/1307945).

Comment: oh yeah separability was the main concern, so the complex ones are separable... now it's clear why the complex Gaussians are required !