# Why we need Laplacian for edge detection?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, derivative

I am studying some trivial computer vision processing techniques and I came across edge detection algorithms. IMO sharp changes in the gradient are enough indications to detect the edges in an image but most of the modern edge detection algorithms use `Laplacian` with second derivation to do the same task.

Q1. Are we using second derivative because the change in flux is a much better indicator for edges?
Q2. Can we use something other than Laplacian?

Comment: "most of the modern edge detection algorithms use Laplacian with second derivation" [citation needed] -- I doubt this is true.

Answer (score 2):

"Need" or "Want"?

Q1:  The second derivative avoids the problem of a gradually changing color being "greyish".

Q2:  Yes.

Here is one:

[After advice about detecting focus quality of objects in a photo detected using YoloV3](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/58341/after-advice-about-detecting-focus-quality-of-objects-in-a-photo-detected-using/58427#58427)

It is based on how planar the color.  Very planar means no edge.

There are many, many other variations of these techniques possible.